# How can we view monoids as lax functors?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, 2-categories

Let $*_2$ be the terminal $2-$category, $V$ be a monoidal category with unit object $I$ and $\mathbf BV$ be its delooping, i.e the $2-$category with $ob(\mathbf BV) = \{*\}$ and $\text{Hom}_{\mathbf BV}(*,*) = V$ and composition given by

$$\text{Hom}_{\mathbf BV}(*,*) \times \text{Hom}_{\mathbf BV}(*,*) \rightarrow \text{Hom}_{\mathbf BV}(*,*)$$

$$ = $$

$$\otimes:V \times V \rightarrow V$$

The unit of this composition is given by the unit object in $V$.

I am told that a lax $2-$functor $F:*_2 \rightarrow \mathbf BV$ is the same as a monoid in $V$. The problem is that I just can't get it to work out on paper.

Let $F$ be such a lax functor, denote the identity $1-$morphism in $*_2$ by $id_1$ and the identity $2-$morphism by $id_2$.

Now, a monoid in $V$ consists of an object $M$, a morphism $\mu: M \otimes M \rightarrow M$ and a morphism $\iota:I \rightarrow M$

I understand that we get $M = Fid_1$ but how do we get $\mu$?

The only thing I can think of is that we have an "associator"

$$\mu: M = F(id_1) = F(id_1 \circ id_1) \rightarrow F(id_1) \circ F(id_1)= M \circ M = M \otimes M$$

$$\mu: M \rightarrow M \otimes M $$

but it goes the wrong way?

The "unitor" $\iota : F(id_1) \rightarrow id_{F*}$

($\{ * \} = ob(*_2)$)

gives us a map $\iota: M \rightarrow I$

...that also goes the wrong way!

It would seem that lax functors $*_2 \rightarrow \mathbf B V$ are really equivalent to $co$monoids in $V$!

What is going on here?

Comment: Shouldn't a lex $2$-functor have a map $F(f)\circ F(g) \to F(f\circ g)$, not the other way around ? Just like lax monoidal functors ? (note that $*_2$ is the delooping of the terminal monoidal category, so lax $2$-functors $*_2\to BV$ should just be lax monoidal functors $* \to V$, i.e. monoids in $V$)

Comment: I should have mentioned this but my source is the nlab: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-functor @MaximeRamzi which says that we are given a map $F(f \circ g) \rightarrow F(f) \circ F(g)$

Comment: I would say that's a mistake in the nLab. Of course if you require the $2$-cells to be invertible it makes no difference so that's probably what happened when writing, but the $2$-cells should be in the direction I indicate (see here for lax monoidal functors : https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+functor  or here for lax $2$-functors : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax_functor or this paper by Ross Street, definition 1 ( a special case, but it should be clear: http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=CTGDC_1972__13_3_217_0)

Comment: As @MaximeRamzi said, a lax functor comes with a morphism $F(f)\circ F(g)\to F(f\circ g)$. A oplax functor comes with a morphism $F(f \circ g)\to F(f)\circ F(g)$. If you talk - as the linked n-lab article does - about (be it strict or pseudo) 2-functors it does not matter wich direction you make part of the definition: It boils down to a pseudo 2-functor being "both" a lax and oplax functor in a suitable way (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/companion+pair). As a result: Lax Functor-> Monoid, Oplax Functor -> Comonoid

Comment: You're right: the nLab page "2-functor" is wrong.  I haven't looked at the history, but my guess is that someone wrote the definition of pseudofunctor without thinking about the direction, since as Gerrit said it doesn't matter in that case, and then (or perhaps before) someone else added a comment that a lax functor is like a pseudofunctor with noninvertible coherences without noticing that the coherences for the pseudofunctor had been written the wrong way.  I'll fix it.